# Rider doesn't see NetCore 3.0

Tags: linux, .net-core-3.0, rider

I had used VS CODE before. But now I would like to try JetBrains Rider. Currently, I have only NetCore 3.0. But before I had 2.2. I had removed old NetCore and installed new one. I am trying to create new project. But Rider don't see NetCore 3.0.

[image: error]

I did not see ability to change NetCore SDK. My operation system is Linux Mint 18. I have only one NetCore version. And it's 3.0.

[image: error]

Why it's happening?

Comment: Which dotnet executable path was detected by Rider in "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build" (["Configure" dropdown ->Settings]  on the Welcome screen)? Please, attach a screenshot to the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-28207. Also, you can try to set a custom path to dotnet.exe in these settings.
Please, clarify how did you installed dotnet to the home folder. Was it some default installation configuration?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is pretty common problem. I have solved it by specifying path to `.Net Sdk` manually. This is the screen of settings:

[image]

1. Specify path to `.NET` binary file. It is usually has the following path `/home/<your_user>/dotnet/dotnet`
2. Specify path to `MSBuild` file. For example my path is the next : `/home/aleksej/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview6-012264/MSBuild.dll`
3. Save
4. Profit!

P.S. My operation system is Linux Mint 19.1. And version of `.Net Core` is not important in this case.

#### Update

I forgot about one important moment. If you need to change `.NET` version for your solution, you have to place special `global.json` file in the root of your solution. If you are changing `.NET` version for a project - put `global.json` on the project root path.

Example of `global.json` for changing `.NET` version:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.300"
  }
}
```

Comment: This updates Rider's settings globally, not just for the current project, as far as I can tell.  I am finding I have to switch back and forth between the versions as I open one project vs. the other.  It would be nice if this setting were saved per project.

Comment: Also, make sure the version of MS Build selected supports .Net Core 3, such as MS Build 16.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to find the location of your sdk then write the following command: **dotnet --list-sdks**. It has to show you **3.1.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]** or similar to it. If it's not then consider it installed using the following guide [Install .NET Core on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux) . Then select the **dotnet** file in .NET CORE CLI executable path, with it's respective **MSBuild.dll** .
[image]

**PD:**  Remember to save the changes globally!!!.

Answer (score 1):

what solved for me was remove the .idea folder and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use the Jetbrain MSE build

[image]

I have to do some set of things to work, due to the windows security I have some issue

On windows 11 do this

1. launch powershell as an admin
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
3. Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
4. Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted

IGNORE THE ERRORS

on windows 10 do this

1. launch powershell as an admin}
2. run get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage
3. if it doesn't work do this
4. run Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppXManifest.xml"
5. run get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage

Then follow the instruction from here

https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006365380